# How to make missing values to blank in a REST request body

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, annotations

My REST controller :

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/people")
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository people;

    @Transactional
    @RequestMapping(path = "/{personId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ResponseEntity<?> update(
            @PathVariable String personId,
            @RequestBody PersonDTO dto) {

        // get the entity by ID
        Person p = people.findOne(personId); // we assume it exists

        // update ONLY entity attributes that have been defined
        if(/* dto.getFirstName is defined */)
            p.setFirstName = dto.getFirstName;

        if(/* dto.getLastName is defined */)
            p.setLastName = dto.getLastName;

        System.out.println(dto);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(p);
    }
}
```

My People DTO :

```
 private class PersonDTO {
        private String firstName;
        private String lastName;
        private List<String> designations;
        private String location;    
        /* getters and setters ... */
    }
```

I'm not passing the value designations in my REST request made through postman here and i see the values in the DTO while debuging in local or when printing, it says the designations is "Null" but i want it to be seen as blank arraylist. How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing stopping you from defining the your `PersonDto` like so:

`private List<String> designations = new ArrayList<>();`

Meaning that even if the client sends null you'll be deserializing into an empty list.

Comment: Tried this but it isnt working for some reason

Answer (score 0):

First initialize your designations array in PersonDTO like so:

```
    private List<String> designations = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Then make the following changes to your setter method for designations

```
    public void setDesignations(List<String> designations) {
        if (designations != null)
            this.designations = designations;
    }
```